# ReactDOM RSS renderToString production error

Tags: reactjs, webpack, react-hot-loader, server-side-rendering

I created new boilerplate for react16.

https://github.com/jasonvillalon/react16-boilerplate

its working when running in development using:

```
npm start
npm start:webpack
```

but when running in production it throws error on renderToString

```
NODE_ENV=production npm start
```

the webpack succeeds without error but when rendering the page the error occur:

```
ERROR: TypeError: Cannot set property 'getCurrentStack' of undefined
at setCurrentDebugStack (webpack:///./node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.node.development.js?:1816:48)
at ReactDOMServerRenderer.read (webpack:///./node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.node.development.js?:2225:13)
at renderToString (webpack:///./node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.node.development.js?:2494:29)
at _callee$ (webpack:///./src/server.jsx?:66:49)
at tryCatch (/Users/jasonvillalon/Documents/fun-projects/from-scratch/node_modules/babel-polyfill/node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:65:40)
at Generator.invoke [as _invoke] (/Users/jasonvillalon/Documents/fun-projects/from-scratch/node_modules/babel-polyfill/node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:303:22)
at Generator.prototype.(anonymous function) [as next] (/Users/jasonvillalon/Documents/fun-projects/from-scratch/node_modules/babel-polyfill/node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:117:21)
at step (webpack:///./src/server.jsx?:27:191)
at eval (webpack:///./src/server.jsx?:27:437)
at new Promise (<anonymous>)
```

any body have an idea what is going on?

Best Regards,
Jason

Comment: changing NODE_ENV=production cause the error. so my work around for now is to make NODE_ENV=staging or NODE_ENV=development. cant use production :|

Comment: Ever get past this?

Comment: FYI, I got some help and figured out this is because a dev version of react-dom was being run with NODE_ENV=production. https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/13276

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that, in Webpack, you've set the following:

```
let config = {
  mode: "development",
....
```

But either on the Winblows / DOS command line you've set:

```
set NODE_ENV=production
```

Or on Linux you've set

```
export NODE_ENV=production
```

Or possibly in your webpack.config.js you've set:

```
let config = {
  ...

  new webpack.DefinePlugin({
    "process.env": {
      NODE_ENV: JSON.stringify("production")
    }
  })
```

To fix this, you either need to fix the top part:

```
let config = {
  mode: "production",
....
```

or unset the NODE_ENV environment variable.

Credit goes to @Jordan M Alperin from the comments above.